# how i can add already existing contacts to campaign ? (no database)

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
trigger AddContacts2 on Campaign (before update) {

    List<CampaignMember> members = new List<CampaignMember>();

    for ( Campaign cam : Trigger.new) {
        if (cam.Name == 'John Cena') {
            CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = '7017F000000TzWAQA0', ContactId = '0037F000004yHY8QAM', Status = 'Sent');

            members.add(cm);
        }

        try{
            insert members;
        }catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occured: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Campaign Member is the junction object between Campaign and Contact.
You need to create record in that object.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to query existing contact and add them

```
trigger AddContacts2 on Campaign (before update) {

    List<CampaignMember> members = new List<CampaignMember>();
    List<Contact> conList = [Select id from contact LIMIT 1000];
    for ( Campaign cam : Trigger.new) {
        if (cam.Name == 'John Cena') {
            for(contact co : conList) {
            CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam.id, ContactId = co.id, Status = 'Sent');

            members.add(cm);
          }
        }

        try{
            insert members;
        }catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occured: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you select which all contact you want to add here because there are very good chances that you hit the SF governor limit here. Also do you really want to add All contact to Campaign Name John Cena and you might want to add different contact to different campaign.

From standard lit view you can use Standard Add to Campaign functionality.
[image]

Comment: instead of trigger can u tell me how i can directly add contacts i have a button and on click of that i want the contacts should update in a campaign

Comment: @KanchanSingh check my updated answer.

Comment: i have a visual force page and a class which give me this output:

Comment: @KanchanSingh then you can use the trigger code and all contact will be added.

Comment: how i can trigger the code on my visual force page?

<apex:pageBlock title="Contact">
   <apex:outputPanel id="contactDetails">
<button type="button" onclick="??????????">Add to Campaign!</button> 
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conList}" var="con" id="conlist" title="Contact">
     <apex:column value="{!con.Name}"/>

what i need to write on on click my trigger name is    addcontacts2

Comment: i have a trigger but from where to run means how do i know my contacts update in campaign how to use the trigger code ? as i am new to it please help

Answer (score 0):

There is a Lookup to Contact in Campaign Member object.
Using a SOQL, you can find the Contact as well as the Campaign and then create a Campaign member.

```
Campaign campaignObject = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign LIMIT 1]; //you can apply the filter as per your needs
Contact contacObject = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1]; //you can apply the filter as per your needs
CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = campaignObject.Id, ContactId = contacObject.Id, Status = 'Sent');
insert cm;
```

Comment: do i need to write this code in a class method and how i can add the campaign id = '7017F000000TzWA'